# Self-built Qt 5.4 does not uses ICU

Tags: qt, webkit, qtwebkit, icu, qt5.4

I try to build Qt 5.4 from scratch including WebKit with ICU/Unicode support for Windows using VS2013. According to Qt's manuals I'm first setting the environment variables to point to the 32 bit binaries of ICU as downloaded from their webpage:

```
SET INCLUDE=D:\Qt\icu\include;%INCLUDE%
SET LIB=D:\Qt\icu\lib;%LIB%
SET PATH=D:\Qt\icu\include;D:\Qt\icu\lib;%PATH%
```

Next I'm doing a configure

```
configure.bat -commercial -confirm-license -debug-and-release -release -force-debug-info
-nomake tests -nomake examples -qt-zlib -qt-libjpeg -qt-libpng -plugin-sql-sqlite
-no-openssl -opengl dynamic -icu -I D:\Qt\icu\include -L D:\Qt\icu\lib
-prefix D:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\install\
```

This results in folllowing outputs:

```
Third Party Libraries:
    ...
    ICU support.............yes

Additional libraries........-LD:\Qt\icu\lib
```

But after doing "nmake" and "nmake install" I end up with Webkit-DLL's that do not depend on ICU and therefore fail to display my webpages containing Unicode.

So...any idea what is wrong here and why Qt does not make use of ICU although it recognises it correctly and does not show any build/link errors?

Thanks!